# How to send a FormCollection in the POST method in C #?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is the code I have, but I only send String, how do I change it to send a FormCollection?

```
public String peticionUrlPost_2(String url, FormCollection parametro)
{
HttpWebRequest HttpWRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
HttpWRequest.Headers.Set("Pragma", "no-cache");
HttpWRequest.Timeout = 300000;
HttpWRequest.Method = "POST";
HttpWRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

byte[] PostData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parametro);

HttpWRequest.ContentLength = PostData.Length;
Stream tempStream = HttpWRequest.GetRequestStream();
tempStream.Write(PostData, 0, PostData.Length);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWRequest.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
String respuesta = readStream.ReadToEnd();
tempStream.Close();

return respuesta;
```

}

Comment: Is this method a Controller Action with [HttpPost]?

Comment: If the call I want to do is by http post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually simple, if you are using the razor view engine below is the example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("peticionUrlPost_2", "AnyControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{

    //Your all form fields like below
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StringData)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.data)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Data)

    <input type="submit" value="Submit strongly type synchronous form" />
}
```

useful link:https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Form-Submit-Post-example.aspx

Hope above information was helpful, kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: But as I do if the FormCollection and arrives as parameter to the method, and is only send by POST

Comment: yes it will be send  all the controls values  as  form collection with http post. additionally you can also send the route values . And one more thing kindly mention [HttpPost] in the action method that receives the form collection